# CouchDB replications not starting when new replication added

Tags: couchdb

When I add a replication to CouchDB, it doesn't start. i.e. I get the following doc after saving:

```
{
   "_id": "xxx",
   "_rev": "yyy",
   "target": "https://user:pswd.domain/db",
   "source": "db",
   "create_target": true,
   "continuous": true,
   "user_ctx": {
       "name": "admin",
       "roles": [
           "_admin"
       ]
   },
   "owner": "admin"
}
```

Usually after creating a replication, the replication is triggered and the doc updated to include:

```
   "_replication_state": "triggered" or "error",
   "_replication_state_time": "some time",
   "_replication_id": "some ID"
```

I am using CouchDB 1.6.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. What could cause this to happen? Replication was working fine until about an hour ago when 80 of 140 or so replications failed at once.

There are 60 replications that are seen as 'triggered' in couch. But the _active_tasks endpoint only shows 46.

Comment: the problem was caused by dodgy traffic flooding our server. So not Couch related at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out our server was experiencing high traffic from super dodgy origins. This was causing replications to timeout, and not allowing replications to restart. The Nginx access logs seemed to show repeated attempts at fishing for insecure PHP settings and open MySQL databases